# Qpid JMS Options for CloudBees?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, cloudbees, qpid

I know that CloudBees don't provide a Message Queue service. In my Java EE app, I have use RabbitMQ as a Broker, Qpid JMS as client. It doesn't work due to:

> [#|2013-11-09T20:21:45.203+0000|INFO|glassfish 4.0|org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;_TimeMillis=1384028505203;_LevelValue=800;|
>     WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from javaeetutorial.websimplemessage.SenderBean because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.jms.Message not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.|#]

Do you have any solution make it work in CloudBees. Does CloudBees support Qpid?

Thank you in advance.
Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as container is a `javaEE Web profile` one, you have to provide JMS api jar in your war.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong a technology partner of Cloudbees provides MQ(Rabbit) -> CloudAMQP (http://www.cloudbees.com/platform-service-cloudamqp.cb)